# TypeError: Cannot read property '_scope' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, this, httpbackend

I get that error when I run my test in Jasmine. I'm trying to create a test for a mock ajax call. The data itself is not important, I'd just like to see the test run. My code:

```js
    export interface IMockScope extends ng.IScope {
        promotion: any;
        prometricId: string;
    }

    export class MockController {

        private _mockService: MockService;
        private _scope: IMockScope;

        constructor($scope: IMockScope, mockService: MockService) {

            // assigning scope and service
            this._mockService = mockService;

            if ($scope === undefined) {
                throw ("exception");
            }
            if (typeof($scope) === "MockController") {
                console.log("I am the right type");
            }
            this._scope = $scope;

            // getting a prometric ID for the promotion to load
            this._scope.prometricId = "xxx";


            // loading a promotion through a service call
            this._mockService.GetPromotion(this._scope.prometricId).then(function (data: any) {
                this._scope.promotion = data;
            }, null);

        }
    }

    export class MockService {

        private _$http: ng.IHttpService;
        private _$q: ng.IQService;

        constructor($http: ng.IHttpService, $q: ng.IQService) {
            this._$http = $http;
            this._$q = $q;
        }

        GetPromotion(prometricId: string): ng.IPromise<any> {

            var deferred = this._$q.defer();
            var data = {
                prometricId: prometricId
            };

            var promotion: any;

            this._$http.get("/PreEval/GetPromotion").then(function (data: any) {
                promotion = data;
                deferred.resolve(promotion);
            }, null);

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }

    var mockApp = angular.module('mockApp', []);
    //mockApp.controller('MyController', MyController);
    mockApp.controller('MyController', ["$scope", "mockService", function ($scope: IMockScope, mockService: MockService) {
        return new MockController($scope, mockService);
    }]);

    mockApp.factory("mockService", ["$http", "$q", function ($http: ng.IHttpService, $q: ng.IQService) {
        return new MockService($http, $q);
    }]);
```

My test in Jasmine:

```js
describe("Mock Controller", function () {

        var controller: MockController;
        var scope: IMockScope;
        var $http: ng.IHttpService;
        var $q: ng.IQService;
        var mockService: MockService;
        var backEnd: ng.IHttpBackendService;

        beforeEach(function () {
            angular.mock.module("mockApp");
        });

        beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService, _$http_: ng.IHttpService, _$q_: ng.IQService,
                                    _mockService_: MockService, $httpBackend: ng.IHttpBackendService) {

            scope = <IMockScope> $rootScope.$new();
            $http = _$http_;
            $q = _$q_;
            mockService = _mockService_;
            backEnd = $httpBackend;

            backEnd.when("GET", "/PreEval/GetPromotion").respond(
                {
                    "Success": true,
                    "ErrorMessage": "",
                    "Result": [
                        { "ContactTypeId": 2, "Name": "Coworker" },
                        { "ContactTypeId": 3, "Name": "Family" },
                        { "ContactTypeId": 5, "Name": "Fresh" },
                        { "ContactTypeId": 1, "Name": "Friend" }
                    ]
                });

        }));


        it("should have data", () => {
            
            controller = new MockController(scope, mockService);
            backEnd.flush();
            expect(scope.promotion).toBeDefined();
        });

    });
}
```

I've tried looking at similar questions but nothing's helped. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        this._mockService.GetPromotion(this._scope.prometricId).then(function (data: any) {
            this._scope.promotion = data;
        }, null);
```

You're losing `this` context within the function here. Use an arrow function instead:

```
        this._mockService.GetPromotion(this._scope.prometricId).then(data => {
            this._scope.promotion = data;
        }, null);
```